# Deploy SignalR on two load balancing web servers

Tags: signalr, web-farm

I want to support real time update feature in my web app, and great I found SignalR. It's very easy and interesting. But when coming to deploy to production servers, it makes me a standstill.

Currently, our web apps run on two web servers (IIS) load balanced. So to get SignalR up, we must support Service Bus.

With Redis, I can't see any implementation for Windows that ready for production. With Windows Azure we can't use it because of some company policy.
And with the new Windows Server Service Bus, I read and see that it's just support a farm with 1 or 3 servers.

So, are there any available options for me to choose? I really impressed with the capabilities of SignalR and want to see it in our web app.

Comment: Hi MillDol , Found any solution ?

Answer (score 6):

If you can switch to SignalR 2.0 then you can download the NuGet package **Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SqlServer** which will handle load balancing for you.  See [SignalR Scaleout with SQL Server](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-with-sql-server) for simple setup instructions.

As long as the account your application connects to SQL with has permissions to create a schema and tables, there is no SQL setup on your end other than providing a connection string.  The package handles creating the load balancing tables for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are plans to implement a SQL Server based transport in the near future.

You may also want to try the third party [RabbitMQ based transport](https://github.com/mdevilliers/SignalR.RabbitMq).

[RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) will likely be more than performant enough for your needs and supports clustering.

Comment: Thanks el_tone. I will try and come back later !